# Form partial differential equation by eliminating of arbitrary constraint

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Form partial differential equation by eliminating of arbitrary constraint 
$x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 =1$ 
Plz help me.. Plz solve it.. I hv tried a lot bt always got wrong results

Comment: equation or a system of equations?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x,y,z)=x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2-1$. We start with this equation: $$F(x,y,z)=0$$
Taking second order partial derivatives, we obtain this system of equations:
$$\frac{d^2F}{d^2x}=\frac{d^2F}{d^2y}=\frac{d^2F}{d^2z}=0$$

Comment: But the answerof the given question is

Comment: But Answer of the given question is qz=q^2y+zyt